# vaadin beginner- getting SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet error

Tags: java, vaadin

I created a test vaadin project- and when I try to run it on local Tomcat 7 server, this is the error I am getting---

```
 SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Spin the Bottle
javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to load application class: com.anyaservices.spinthebottle.App_Main
at     com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet.init(ApplicationServlet.java:71)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:857)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What have i done wrong here? I just created a Vaadin project using the new project wizard...I did not even add/edit any code to it.

Comment: You are missing lots of information here. Try posting relevant things like web.xml here too. Also, is this the only stacktrace or do you have another one with more info?

Answer (score 0):

Check that "com.anyaservices.spinthebottle.App_Main" path points to a valid Java file contains public class which extends Vaadin Application class.